# Ingresar una imagen y descargarla en Asp.NEt MVC y Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Hola estoy empezando en la programación en ASP.NEt y estoy realizando el ingreso de Datos por medio de procedimientos almacenados. El cual quisiera ingresar imagen a mi base de datos para luego poder listarlo y poder seleccionarlo para mostrar, en si la idea es ingresar y luego mostrar pero con mi controlador que tengo ya que es el cual registra mis datos

```
        public ActionResult Subir(int Cod_Ope,int iMCliente,string Ope_Direc,int ID_Tipo,string Ope_item_Desc,DateTime Ope_Fecha_Esti)
    {

        var resultado = db.sp_Registrar(Cod_Ope, iMCliente, Ope_Direc, ID_Tipo, Ope_item_Desc, Ope_Fecha_Esti);
        return View("_Exito");
    }
```

El cual registra normal en mi base de Datos, Ahora quiero ingresar una imagen a  a mi base de Datos, como podria realizarlo.

Mi procedimiento Almacenado para ingresar a mi base de datos es sp_Registrar().

Donde mi Vista de mi Controlador es la siguiente:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Subir", "Trabajos", FormMethod.Post,new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">|Ingresar Trabajos|</h3>
                    <ul class="panel-tool-options">
                        <li><a data-rel="collapse" href="#"><i class="icon-down-open"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a data-rel="reload" href="#"><i class="icon-arrows-ccw"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a data-rel="close" href="#"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form>
                        @*<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Estado</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("ID_Estado", ViewBag.listaestado as SelectList, new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
                            </div>*@
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Operador</label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("Cod_Ope", ViewBag.listapersona as SelectList, new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Cliente</label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("iMCliente", ViewBag.listacliente as SelectList, new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Direccion</label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ope_Direc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ope_Direc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Servicio</label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("ID_Tipo", ViewBag.listaservicio as SelectList, new { @class = "select2 form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div  class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Descripcion</label>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Ope_item_Desc, new {  @class = "form-control", @cols = 100, @rows = 8 })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ope_Direc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" >Fecha Termino</label>
                                <div id="date-popup" class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text" name="Ope_Fecha_Esti" data-format="D, dd MM yyyy" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        @*<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Archivo</label>
                                <input type="file" id="field-file" class="form-control" name="imagen">
                        </div>*@
                        <button value="Subir" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir Archivo</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que no pude encontrar información al caso. Saludos.

Y como podría realizar que me aparezca un listado

Ejm:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi Store Procedure es sp_GetImage(id)
Donde el sp_GetImagen devuelve el Id ,Descripcion,Usuario,FechaIni,FechaFin,Imagen )-- Mas Detallado en otra vista.

```
public ActionResult Download(int id)
    {
        var context = new Models.OperacionesEntities();
        byte[] imageData = db.sp_GetImage(id);
        if (imageData != null)
        {
            return File(imageData, "image/png"); // igual necesitaras ajustar la extension o tipo de imagen
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Como deberia ingresar mi Store Procedure en el Codigo de Arriba.

Cuando este listado quisiera que al hacer clik en el Link se vaya a Detalles y hay se pueda mostrar la imagen.

Comment: Depende de varios factores, guardaras la imagen en la base de datos, o guardaras la ruta y guardaras el archivo en tu servido?

Comment: Pues son varios pasos, primero debes descargar la imagen que sube el usuario, junto con sus datos personales.  Revisa este articul es muy detallado y viene con codigo fuente https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-upload-imagefile-into-database/

Comment: Como dice @EdgarVazquez Como piensar guardar la imagen ? quieres guardarla en Base de datos o la vas a guardar en una carpeta y despues recuperas la ruta ?

Comment: En la base de datos pienso almacenarlos.por eso puse mi store procedure para integrar la imagen en mi base de datos y en mi store procedure

Comment: Ahí te puse un ejemplo, sin embargo será necesario hacer el comentario de que guardar imágenes en base de datos es considerado una mala práctica ya que esa tabla puede crecer muy rápidamente y generar problema con el mantenimiento de la base datos (backups, migraciones, etc). La recomendación es almacenar los archivos em repositorio (carpeta en el servidor, o mejor aún, en el sistema de archivos de cloud a usar, blobs para azure).

Comment: Entonces para que no sea por base de datos, y se en carpeta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una imagen no es mas que un arreglo de bytes, por lo que store procedure necesitará procesar este arreglo de bytes. Así pues en MVC lo que necesitas hacer para guardar la imagen que el usuario está tratando de subir es convertir tu campo input/file a un arreglo de bytes.

View (nótese el parámetro enctype)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();

            var resultado = db.sp_Registrar(.... , array);
        }

    }

    return View("_Exito");
}
```

Adicionalmente, para mostrar tu imagen en la vista, te recomiendo crear un controlador que maneje el arreglo de imágenes y te regrese la imagen:

Controlller

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var context = new Models.DBEntities();
        byte[] imageData = db.sp_GetImage(...);
        if (imageData != null)
        {
            return File(imageData, "image/png"); // igual necesitaras ajustar la extension o tipo de imagen
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

View

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Index", "Images", new { id = 1 })" />
```